# Running DLR Embedded Scripts in Minimum Security Context

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I need to get pointed in the right direction. I have embedded an Iron Python scripting host into a simple C# application, but now I need to know the best practices for locking down security on a user generated IronPython or IronRuby script.

Specifically, what are the strategies for preventing library imports and isn't there a way in .NET to run a block of code or a thread in a different security context, for instance to prevent file system access? Also, can this context be assigned a built-in level or role rather than an actual user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run scripting host in different appdomain, and setup Security Policies via [Evidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.evidence.aspx) property using [sandboxing API](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/08/08/449050.aspx)

Comment: Sergey, Would that prevent an IronPython open('c:\\file.txt') call?

Comment: not sure about Python, but if it opens file using System.IO namespace definitely yes.

Comment: I guess you're an IronRuby guy. Would a locked down AppDomain prevent ruby's native file methods from working?

Comment: Of course! remember that IronRuby's native file methods are eventually System.IO operations.